# jQuery Dialog not appearing when called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am trying to get a modal loading dialog to pop up while I make an ajax call but it is not showing up in the onClick function. If I slow it down with firebug and step through the loading panel will show up. Is this just javascript running ahead of itself? Is there a better way to do this?

```
$(function(){
     $("#loading_panel").dialog({
                                 modal:true,
                                 position:'center',
                                 minHeight:40
                                });

     $("a.view-in-frame").click(function(){
                       $("#loading_panel").dialog('open');
                       $("#tabs").hide();
                       var blog = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'blog').load(('blog_reader.php?blog='+this.href)), $("#loading_panel").dialog('close'));
                       $("#content_wrap").append(blog);
                       return false;
                 });
})
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having much the same problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I can't even remember how I got around the problem now :P

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, try setting the 'autoOpen' to false when creating the dialog:

```
$("#loading_panel").dialog({
                             modal:true,
                             position:'center',
                             minHeight:40,
                             autoOpen:false
                            });
```

At the moment you are telling the dialog to open when it is created. This should prevent that behaviour.

Comment: Either way, it should be in there. :)

Answer (score 1):

@ErsatzRyan

Have you tried set your javascript function to load after your document is ready?

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Your functions

});
```

And as @Nat Ryall said, you must set your autoOpen to `false`, otherwise your dialog won't open twice.

And another thing, try to call your `$(".selector").dialog("open")` after you done everything. You're telling your function to call your dialog before it has loaded it's content.

Comment: the $(function () { }); syntax he's using is equivalent. See the [spec for ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: This is what fixed it for me.  Creating the dialog before the document is ready apparently does not work, even if no errors are thrown and you don't attempt to show it.